# Windows: ScrollViewer in UWP don't works combined with datagrid

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, datagrid, scrollviewer

I'm trying to create a ScrollViewer, but it don't scrolls when I use the 
mouse wheel and I don't know what I do wrong :/

I use the newst Windows(Windows 10 1903 - the may update)

My XAML page:

```
<RelativePanel x:Name="RelativePanel">
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <Grid
            Margin="0,0,0,0"
            RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
            RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True">

                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <toolkit:DataGrid
                x:Name="DataGrid"
                CanUserReorderColumns="False"
                RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal"                        
                PreparingCellForEdit="DataGrid_PreparingCellForEdit"
                RightTapped="DataGrid_RightTapped"
                ContextFlyout="{StaticResource DataGridContextMenu}"
                Margin="20,127,10,-182"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="3">

                    <toolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
                        <toolkit:DataGridTextColumn
                        Header="Name"
                        Binding="{Binding DataGridName}"/>
                        <toolkit:DataGridTextColumn
                        Header="Aktivierungstaste"
                        Binding="{Binding DataGridButtonToEnable}"/>
                        <toolkit:DataGridTextColumn
                        Header="Klicktaste"
                        Binding="{Binding DataGridButtonToClick}"/>
                        <toolkit:DataGridTextColumn
                        Header="Klicks pro Sekunde"
                        Binding="{Binding DataGridCps}"/>
                        <toolkit:DataGridTextColumn
                        Header="Abweichung"                            
                        Binding="{Binding DataGridRandom}"/>
                    </toolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
                </toolkit:DataGrid>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </RelativePanel>
```

Comment: I tried to use your code snippet to make a local project to reproduce your issue. But apparently, I cannot do it. Your code is incomplete. I did not understand your XAML layout. For example, your set `Grid.ColumnSpan="3"` for DataGrid, but I did not see your define the `Grid.ColumnDefinitions`. You set `RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"` for Grid, I do not think it will work. You should set `RelativePanel.xxx` for ScrollViewer, instead of Grid etc.

Comment: Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [mcve].